Why are there different results from returned from this test in python3.8 and python 3.11
I have a test that validates urls that looks like this
def test_rfc2732_urls(self):
        def valid(v):
            self.assertTrue(validate_c_db(v))
            self.assertFalse(validate_c_db("https://" + v))

trying to validate url which will have IPV6 in it
not_allowed("[::FFFF:192.168.1.10]:80/index.html")

The validate_c_db function looks like this
def validate_c_db(value: str) -> bool:
    if not value or not isinstance(value, str):
        return False
    return bool(CdbUrl(value).process())

The url is then validated against uri, scheme, path, port, query etc...
class Uri:
    def __init__(self, value: str):
        self.value = value
        self.tokens = RE_URI.match(value)
        self.scheme = self.tokens.group(1)
        self.authority = self.tokens.group(2)
        self.path = self.tokens.group(3)
        self.query = self.tokens.group(4)
        self.fragment = self.tokens.group(5)

    def process(self) -> Optional[str]:
        """
        Process given uri value and return a reconstructed string
        If string is not returned - this means value is invalid
        """
        if RE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS.search(self.value):
            return
        if not self.scheme:
            return

        # If has authority then path should be empty or start with /
        if self.authority:
            if self.path and not self.path.startswith(TOK_SLASH):
                return
        # if not authority then no //
        elif self.path.startswith(TOK_DOUBLE_SLASH):
            return

        if not (RE_SCHEME.match(self.scheme.lower())):
            return

        return self._re_create()

    def _re_create(self):
        tokens = []
        tokens += [self.scheme, TOK_COLON]
        if self.authority:
            tokens += [TOK_DOUBLE_SLASH, self.authority]
        tokens.append(self.path)
        if self.query:
            tokens += [TOK_QUERY, self.query]
        if self.fragment:
            tokens += [TOK_FRAGMENT, self.fragment]
        return "".join(tokens)


class HttpsUri(Uri):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.port = None  # type: Optional[str]
        self.user_info = None  # type: Optional[str]
        self.host = None  # type: Optional[str]
        self.ipv6 = False  # type: bool
        self.ipv4 = False  # type: bool

    def process(self) -> Optional[str]:
        ignore_port = False

        if not super().process():
            return

        if self.scheme != TOK_HTTPS:
            return

        if not self.authority:
            return

        authority_token = self.authority
        at_sign_location = authority_token.rfind(TOK_AT)
        if at_sign_location == 0:
            return
        if at_sign_location > 0:
            self.user_info = authority_token[:at_sign_location]
            authority_token = authority_token[at_sign_location + 1 :]

        if authority_token.startswith(TOK_IPV6_START):
            if RE_IPV6_END.search(authority_token):
                ignore_port = True
            elif RE_IPV6_PORT_END.search(authority_token):
                ignore_port = True
                port_end_match = RE_PORT_END.search(authority_token)
                if not port_end_match:
                    return
                self.port = port_end_match.group(1)
            else:
                return

        if not ignore_port and RE_COLON_END.search(authority_token):
            port = RE_PORT_END.search(authority_token)
            if not port:
                return
            self.port = port.group(1)

        self.host = authority_token
        if self.port:
            port_pos = len(authority_token) - len(self.port) - 1
            self.host = authority_token[:port_pos]

        if (
            self.host.startswith(TOK_DASH)
            or RE_DASH_END.search(self.host)
            or RE_DASH_END.search(authority_token)
        ):
            return

        try:
            self._check_host()
        except ValueError:
            return

        try:
            self._check_port()
        except ValueError:
            return

        return super()._re_create()

    def _check_host(self):
        if not self.host:
            raise ValueError("Host is missing")
        if self.host.startswith("["):
            self.ipv6 = True
            check_ipv6(self.host[1:-1])
        if RE_IPV4_ROUGH.match(self.host):
            self.ipv4 = True
            check_ipv4(self.host)

    def _check_port(self):
        if not self.port:
            return
        int_port = int(self.port)
        if int_port < 0 or int_port > 65535:
            raise ValueError("Invalid port")


class CdbUrl(HttpsUri):
    def __init__(self, value: str):
        super().__init__("https://" + value)
        self.original = value

    def process(self) -> Optional[str]:
        tokens = RE_SCHEME_START.match(self.original)
        if tokens and tokens.group(0):
            return

        if TOK_SPACE in self.original or RE_TEL_OR_NOT_DOMAIN.match(self.original):
            return

        return super().process() and not self.user_info

    def _check_host(self):
        if not self.host:
            raise ValueError("Host is missing")
        if self.host.startswith("["):
            self.ipv6 = True
            check_not_ours(check_ipv6(self.host[1:-1]))
        if RE_IPV4_ROUGH.match(self.host):
            self.ipv4 = True
            check_not_ours(check_ipv4(self.host))
        if RE_BAD_HOSTS.match(self.host):
            raise ValueError("Bad host detected")
        if not self.ipv6 and not self.ipv4:
            if not validate_hostname(self.host, CAT_DB_HOST_LABEL_COUNT):
                raise ValueError("Host format is not valid")

The failure occurs specifically for IPV6 urls, and the regex's i am matching against for IPV6 urls are
RE_IPV6_END = re.compile(r"[\]]$")
RE_IPV6_PORT_END = re.compile(r"[\]]:\d+?")
TOK_IPV6_START = r"["

When i test by passing this url specifically [::FFFF:192.168.1.10]:80/index.html the test passes on python3.8 and fails on 3.11 or rather 3.11 returns True
def test_cat_db():
    url = "[::FFFF:192.168.1.10]:80/index.html"
    cdb_instance = CdbUrl(url)
    result = cdb_instance.process()
    print(f"Result: {result}")

The above function will print Result: True in python3.11 but Result: None in python3.8
i cannot figure out why, i though it might be UNICODE issue so i tested by adding RE_IPV6_END = re.compile(r"[\]]$", re.UNICODE) but same thing happens, according to rfc2732 * It defines a syntax
for IPv6 addresses and allows the use of "[" and "]" within a URI
explicitly for this reserved purpose*
(EDIT):Here are all the additional regex's used to match urls
RE_URI = re.compile(r"(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?")
RE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS = re.compile(
    r"[^a-z0-9:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.\-_~%]", re.IGNORECASE
)
RE_SCHEME = re.compile(r"^[a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*$")
RE_IPV6_END = re.compile(r"[\]]$", re.RAW)
RE_IPV6_PORT_END = re.compile(r"[\]]:\d+?")
RE_PORT_END = re.compile(r":(\d+)$")
RE_COLON_END = re.compile(r":(.*)$")
RE_DASH_END = re.compile(r"-$")
# Only alphanum wih -, +, can be a telephone number or non domain like localhost
RE_TEL_OR_NOT_DOMAIN = re.compile(r"^[a-z0-9\-+]+$")
RE_SCHEME_START = re.compile(r"^([a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*://)(.*)$", re.IGNORECASE)
RE_IPV4_ROUGH = re.compile(r"(\d+)([.](\d+)){3}")
# This checks if hosts match `co.uk`, `co.in` etc.
RE_BAD_HOSTS = re.compile(^co\\.(uk|in|nz|il|id|cr|jp|kr|cp)$, re.IGNORECASE)
RE_TLD_NO_NUMBER_END = re.compile(r"[0-9]+$")
RE_HOST_SECTION = re.compile(r"(?!-)[a-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)$")

TOK_HTTPS_SCHEME = r"https://"
TOK_HTTP_SCHEME = r"http://"
TOK_HTTPS = r"https"
TOK_SLASH = r"/"
TOK_DOUBLE_SLASH = r"//"
TOK_SPACE = r" "
TOK_DASH = r"-"
TOK_COLON = r":"
TOK_QUERY = r"?"
TOK_FRAGMENT = r"#"
TOK_IPV6_START = r"["
TOK_AT = "@"

And a few additional functions
def validate_hostname(hostname: str, min_labels=1) -> bool:
    if not hostname or not isinstance(hostname, str):
        return False

    if hostname[-1] == ".":
        hostname = hostname[:-1]

    if len(hostname) > HOST_MAX_LEN:
        return False

    labels = hostname.split(".")

    if RE_TLD_NO_NUMBER_END.match(labels[-1]):
        return False

    if len(labels) < min_labels:
        return False

    return all(RE_HOST_SECTION.match(label) for label in labels)
def check_ipv4(ip: str):
    try:
        ipv4 = ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip)
    except ipaddress.AddressValueError as ex:
        raise ValueError("Invalid IP address {!r}".format(ip)) from ex

    return ipv4


def check_ipv6(ip: str):
    try:
        ipv6 = ipaddress.IPv6Address(ip)
    except ipaddress.AddressValueError as ex:
        raise ValueError("Invalid IP address {!r}".format(ip)) from ex

    return ipv6


Not related to your problem, but it doesn't make sense to end a pattern with a non-greedy quantifier. And since you use re.search and you don't need to extract anything: r"[\]]:\d+?" should be for the same result r"]:\d". Note that ] is not a special character.

Can you post a Minimal, Reproducible Example? The current code has too many missing definitions for testing. Also note that Python 3.11 had some changes in its regular expression engine.

What is RE_URI, RE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS, RE_SCHEME, RE_SCHEME_START, TOK_DOUBLE_SLASH, TOK_QUERY, TOK_FRAGMENT, TOK_HTTPS, TOK_AT, RE_PORT_END, RE_COLON_END, TOK_DASH, RE_DASH_END, check_ipv6, RE_IPV4_ROUGH, check_ipv4, etc, etc...

@BoppreH i think MRE can be done with the provided code i posted the function i used in flask shell to test the output, perhaps the only thing i might need to include is the rest of the regex's trincot asked for, will add it to edit

@mr_no The provided code is neither reproducible nor minimal. Please include all definitions, and trim everything not necessary.
